# Can i remove and add command on GestureRecognize?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a page where user can swap labels. So I have a ExtendedWebView CZ and ExtendedWebView EN once user presses button i need them to swap. I have decided to swap these ExtendedWebView in the bac of my page as that seemed much easier however both these commes with button that each fires different pop up. So if i swap ExtendedWebView CZ i need the button that fires CZ pop up to be swapped also.

This is how i am changing my ExtendedWebViews

```
 bool isSwap = false;
        private void ChangePosition(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            isSwap = !isSwap;
            czView.RemoveBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty);
            enView.RemoveBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty);


            if (isSwap)
            {
                btnChangePositions.Text = "EN/CZ";
                czView.SetBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty,("EN"));
                enView.SetBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty, ("CZ"));

            }
            else
            {
                btnChangePositions.Text = "CZ/EN";
                czView.SetBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty, ("CZ"));
                enView.SetBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty, ("EN"));
            }
        }
```

Xaml

```
   <Label
x:Name="makeLargerEN"
FontFamily="{StaticResource IconsFontFamily}"
HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
Text="{Binding MakeLargerEN}"
TextColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
VerticalTextAlignment="End">
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
 <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MakeWebViewLargeEnCommand}" />
  </Label>
```

And this is my pop up in the vIew Model

```
  private async void MakeWebViewLargeEN()
            {
                var popup = new WordAndPhrasePopup(htmlSourceName.Html);
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(popup);
            }
```

I have tried in back of the content page

```
 makeLargerEN.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "MakeLargerEN");
```

Just to swap labels but then the right command doesnt get fired
I have tried this, but gesture doesnt have Command or CommandProperty

```
 makeLargerCZ.SetBinding(GestureRecognizer.Command, new Binding("MakeLargerEN"));
```

I am doing it in the back of COntent page because i am setting up there another swap that goes along with this one.

Comment: why don't just use a Tapped handler in the code behind?  It seems like you are making this more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: because that doesnt really solve anything, i still need to swap them. If I swap labels and i need to swap these buttons too because they are connected to the labels. If just remove and add them then i get an error thats why i decided to try ViewModel

Comment: I dont mind to do it all in ViewModel at all, but i still dont know how to swap if i can swap commands

Comment: again, it seems like you are really over complicating this.  If you were to explain what you are trying to accomplish we might be able to suggest a simpler approach.

Comment: Sorry, i have tried to update the question

Comment: just have both labels use the same command (or handler) and use `isSwap` to determine which popup should be called

Comment: @Vanessa Kensington You could check my answer .

Answer (score 0):

You could remove and add  **GestureRecognize** in code behind .

#### Remove

```
makeLargerEN.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
```

#### Add

```
makeLargerEN.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
      {
         NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
         Command = new Command(() =>
         {
           //...

         }),
      });
```